# How do I Set Up Clustering on Google Maps Web API

Tags: api, google-maps, markerclusterer

I'm trying to add clustering to Google Maps web project, but so far no luck. Here is what is working:

1. Added a few markers
2. Requested user location (code removed).

`markercluster.js` is the library file downloaded from the GitHub project and saved in the public.html file.

I have removed the API key for security.

JavaScript Code in HTML Body

```
    var userPosition;

    var map;
function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {

        //center: {lat: -34.928499, lng: 138.600746},
        center: {lat: -33.86882, lng: 151.209296},
    zoom: 13
        });

var markers = [
    {coords:{lat:-34.923885, lng:138.562042}, content:'<p><strong>British Raj</strong></p>'},
    {coords:{lat:-34.924476, lng:138.561141}, content:'<p><strong>Subway (Torrensville)</strong></p>'},
    {coords:{lat:-34.843645, lng:138.507653}, content:'<p>Banyan Hotel Port Adelaide</p>'},
    {coords:{lat:-34.92366, lng:138.567063}, content:'<p>Abyssinian Restaurant</p>'},
    {coords:{lat:-34.923927, lng:138.561959}, content:'<p>Burger Foundry (Torrensville)</p>'}

];

var gmarkers = [];
for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++){
    //addMarker(markers[i]);
    gmarkers.push(addMarker(markers[i]));
}

function addMarker(props){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position:props.coords,
    map:map,
    icon:'Layer 1.png'
});

if (props.content){
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content:props.content
});

    marker.addListener('click', function(){
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    }
  } 

}
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, gmarkers,{imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});

</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY_REMOVED&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>
<script src="markercluster.js"></stript>
```

***CSS***

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#map {
    height: 80%;
    weidth: 80%;
}
```

Comment: "no luck" or "it doesn't work" is not enough of a problem description. Are the markerclusterer icons where they are supposed to be? Do you get any error in the javascript console?

Comment: I can see the map with markers, but not clustering! There is one error in the console.

Uncaught ReferenceError: MarkerClusterer is not defined
    at (index):72

Comment: Please refer to the link https://medium.com/@sunil.jadhav38/implementing-marker-clustering-is-angular-using-google-charts-6b62a33f3b61

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

1. The creation of the `MarkerClusterer` is outside of the `initMap` function, so it runs before the API is loaded.  Move that inside the `initMap` function.
2. The `addMarker` function doesn't return anything, so everytime you create a marker you add "undefined" to the `gmarkers` array (add: `return marker;` to the end of the function).
3. Based on [the example in the documentation](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering), you need to load `markerclusterer.js` before the Google Maps JavaScript API v3.

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/6x2sze8g/3/)

[image: screenshot of working map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var userPosition;
var gmarkers = [];
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {

    //center: {lat: -34.928499, lng: 138.600746},
    center: {
      lat: -33.86882,
      lng: 151.209296
    },
    zoom: 13
  });

var markers = [
    {coords:{lat:-34.923885, lng:138.562042}, content:'<p><strong>British Raj</strong></p>'},
    {coords:{lat:-34.924476, lng:138.561141}, content:'<p><strong>Subway (Torrensville)</strong></p>'},
    {coords:{lat:-34.843645, lng:138.507653}, content:'<p>Banyan Hotel Port Adelaide</p>'},
    {coords:{lat:-34.92366, lng:138.567063}, content:'<p>Abyssinian Restaurant</p>'},
    {coords:{lat:-34.923927, lng:138.561959}, content:'<p>Burger Foundry (Torrensville)</p>'}

];

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    //addMarker(markers[i]);
    gmarkers.push(addMarker(markers[i]));
    bounds.extend(markers[i].coords);
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);

  function addMarker(props) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: props.coords,
      map: map,
    });

    if (props.content) {
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: props.content
      });

      marker.addListener('click', function() {
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }
    return marker;
  }
  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, gmarkers, {
    imagePath: 'https://unpkg.com/@google/markerclustererplus@4.0.1/images/m'
  });

}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@googlemaps/markerclustererplus/dist/index.min.js"></script>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap">
</script>
```